# Как работают сайты, обрабатывающие код пользователей на различных языках?

Tags: java, c#, python, asp.net, веб-сервер

Например, https://www.codingame.com http://codeforces.com/

Как обрабатывают получаемый от пользователей код на различных языках? 
Куда передают, как компилируются, как тестируют и получают результат?

Comment: В компилятор; как обычно; запускают с передачей данных в стандартный ввод или файл; читают результат из стандартного вывода или файла. Если не вдаваться в мелочи вроде безопасности и ограничения потребляемых ресурсов, всё вписывается в самые основы межпроцессного взаимодействия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Программа, написанная практически на любом языке, может:

- Получить текст, введенный клиентом в форму;
- Сохранить его в файле;
- Запустить другую программу, передав ей аргументы командной строки, например имя файла, сохраненного на предыдущем шаге;
- Перехватить вывод этой программы на консоль -- это могут быть результаты компиляции или выполнения;
- Проанализировать этот вывод и выдать на странице либо какие-то результаты анализа, либо сам вывод, либо то и другое вместе.

  Запускаемая программа может быть либо компилятором и затем, на следующем шаге,  откомпилированной программой пользователя, либо интерпретатором, которому передается текст программы. Используя эти возможности, сайты и делают то, о чем вы спрашиваете.